# generators of $SL_3(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-fields

Is there an explicit description (actually any nice characterization would do) of the generators of $SL_3(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$? I found many references about the generators of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$, but none about $SL_3$. I am particularly interested in the subset of $SL_3(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ consisting of matrices of the form $S = \{I + cE_{21}, I + cE_{32}, I + cE_{31}\} $ where $E_{ij}$ is the matrix with just the $(i,j)$-th entry having a value $c$ and the rest of the entries $0$. All the matrices are $3 \times 3$ matrices here. Do these matrices generate $SL_3(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$? (If yes, can someone point me to a proof of this fact or sketch a proof here?)

Comment: See [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1992-115-01/S0002-9939-1992-1079696-5/S0002-9939-1992-1079696-5.pdf) for example. Every finite group is known to be isomorphic to some subgroup of the symmetric group by Cayley.

Comment: Your set $S$ generates a subgroup of order $p^2$. Two randomly chosen elements will generate the group with high probability.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Oops. That was a silly minor question, I'll edit it out.

Comment: I don't see the reason for the downvote. Anyway, thanks for the comments.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'll accept the answer from your link if you think its worth writing it out.

Comment: A "generator" of a group is senseless. You have a notion of generating subset/family, and "generator" just means "one of the elements in a generating subset/family".

Comment: @YCor I thought I did ask for "generators" and not "generator"?

Comment: "subset (subgroup?) $S=\langle I\dots\rangle$" is confusing. $\langle(\dots)\rangle$ usually means the subgroup generated by $(\dots)$, but if you are interested in generating subsets, you probably rather want to refer to the subset $\{(\dots)\}$, which clearly is not a subgroup.

Comment: generators is senseless as well, for the same reason

Comment: @YCor Yeah, I did mean a subset/family. I mean, as you mentioned already, the other one doesn't even make any sense. If you are really picky, feel free to edit it.

Comment: It's just that the question is very vague, and using vague terms doesn't help. I can't edit if I have so little idea what you're asking. You also didn't answer to my other comment.

Comment: @YCor Apologies, if it was unclear (I'm not very familiar with these things). My question is if there is an explicit generating set known for $SL_3(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$. The matrices arising in my application are diagonal matrices with just one off diagonal entry which could be some field element -- it could be either in the (2,1) or (3,1) or (3,2)-th entries. This is a very specific subset of $SL_3(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ -- I guess there are just $3(p-1)$ such matrices. Do these matrices generate $SL_3(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $e_{ij}(r)=1+rE_{ij}$ ($i\neq j$) and $e_{ij}=e_{ij}(1)$.

Then standard reduction shows that for every field $K$ and $n\ge 0$, the group $\mathrm{SL}_n(K)$ is generated by the matrices $e_{ij}(r)$ when $i,j$ ranges over distinct pairs and $r$ ranges over $K$. In particular, for $K=\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$ ($p$ prime), the $n(n-1)$ matrices $e_{ij}$ generate $\mathrm{SL}_n(K)$.

Actually, the latter result holds for an arbitrary integer $p$. For $p$ prime power, this follows from a similar argument, and general $p\neq 0$ follows from the Chinese remainder theorem. The case $p=0$ is proved directly ($\mathrm{SL}_n(R)$ is generated by the matrices $e_{ij}(r)$ for every Euclidean domain $R$).